# Printing a large table to console

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a `data.table` with more than 10k rows that I'd like to fully print out to the console. Despite the error message you get - increasing `options(max.print=...)` doesn't help - the table still gets cut off (depending on OS with `max.print` set to 15000 it gets cut off at either 1500 or 7500 for me).

I considered using `write.table` instead, but the issue there is that I lose the column alignment that `print` normally provides:

```
dt = data.table(a = c("sdflk", "sdflksdfsdfsdf"), b = c(1,2))
write.table(dt, sep = "\t", quote = F)
#a       b
#1       sdflk   1
#2       sdflksdfsdfsdf  2
```

Is there a way around this limitation?

Here's a large `data.table` if you'd like to play around:

```
dtl = data.table(a = sample(c("sdflk", "sdflksdfsdfsdf"), 15000, T), b = 1:15000)
options(max.print = 15000)
print(as.data.frame(dtl))
print(dtl, nrow = 15000)
```

Comment: Why would you need this printed to the console? Are you sure you don't want it written to a file somewhere or something? What exactly are the requirements?

Comment: Because I want to look at it (this is an Rscript that I `less`). Yes, I'm sure :) Not really sure what you mean requirements - it might be up to 100k rows, probably not any larger.

Comment: So really you just want to write it standard out, not to the console per se.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but I want it formatted like a normal `print` would be.

Comment: The documentation for max.print says it's the number of entries, not rows, so `options(max.print = 15001*ncol(dtl))` works for your example. So you hit 1500 with 10 cols and 7500 with 2 cols, I guess..?

Comment: @Frank - that looks to be the answer - post that.

Comment: You can also try `tabview` (`pip install tabview`)..?

Comment: @Frank thanks - rtfm it is :) Please post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `max.print` (at `?options`) says it's the number of entries, not rows, so

```
options(max.print = (nrow(dtl)+1)*ncol(dtl))
```

seems to work for the example in the OP.

Comment: Thanks again! Of course who and why thought that this is how `print.data.frame` should interpret that option is beyond me... An "entry" for a `data.frame` is clearly a row.

Comment: Yeah, I agree; it's not intuitive. Maybe `print.data.table` can be written so that its `nrow` overrides `max.print` ... not sure that's a good idea, though.

Comment: **and** the error message reads - reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted xxx **rows**; anyway I'll stop ranting - I really wish core R was as responsive as some package developers are to fixing its issues